# Can't access things inside of WP_Query Object

Tags: php, wordpress

Here's what I'm seeing when I do a var_dump on a new `WP_Query` I create:

```
object(WP_Query)#115 (45) {
  ["query_vars"]=>
  array(55) {
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(6) "charity"
    ["order"]=>
    string(3) "ASC"
    ["error"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["m"]=>
    int(0)
    ["p"]=>
    int(0)
    ["post_parent"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["subpost"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ... and so on ...
  }
}
```

The code I used to create it is as follows:

```
$charity = new WP_Query(array(
   'post_type' => 'charity',
   'order'     => 'ASC'
));
```

I've tried to do so many variation of `<?php echo $charity[INSERTSOMETHINGHERE']; ?>` and nothing shows up. I don't use PHP much, but my client insists on a WordPress site. How would I access something like, for say, the `post_type` in that Object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$charity->query_vars['post_type']
```